# XBMC - How to make hulu work in new zealand

Tags: kodi

i've got hulu plugin in my xbmc running on my imac and as you all know, hulu works only in america, so is there anyway to make it work in new zealand using xbmc?

please help guys!

Comment: The question might be improved (and savable!) if you include what you have tried so far and how its failed. As is, I've chosen to vote to close as too localised, but it was a toss up between that and NARQ.

Comment: I have tried to google it but some forum seemed to talk about the website which they suggested to use proxy but I'm new to xbmc and not sure how to use proxy or whatever in xbmc.